# How to get access to a webpage with multi-factor authentication using python

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying to access newclasses.nyu.edu to create a program that involves scraping the website but I need to first login with my student details and then enable MFA from my phone. How can I do this?

I have been able to get the user login details and store it in a dictionary but for some reason it shows invalid password

```
#Getting user_data
def login():

    login_data = {}

    NetID = input("Enter your NetID")
    password = input("Enter your password")

    login_data['j_username'] = NetID
    login_data['j_password'] = password 
    login_data['_eventId_proceed'] = '' 

    return login_data


with requests.Session() as s: #Maintain a session
    url = "https://newclasses.nyu.edu"

    request = s.get(url) #Getting access to the site 

    #soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html5lib') #Scraping the site 

    login_data = login()
    print(login_data)

    request = s.get(url, data = login_data)

    print(request.content)
```

This code prints out the webpage showing an invalid password but what I want is to be able to login and activate the MFA and get access to the site